# How to gzip query results-Python/Airflow

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, gzip, airflow

I am trying to GZIP my query results and write it to a location in Airflow. However I get the error of

> TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

whenever I run my code.

Check out the fp variable in my code:

```
def create_tunnel_postgres():
    try:
        tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder((ssh_host, 22),
                                    ssh_username=ssh_username,
                                    ssh_private_key=pkf,
                                    remote_bind_address=(psql_host,
                                    5432))

            # local_bind_address=('localhost',6543) # could be any available port
        # Start the tunnel

        tunnel.start()
    except:
        print 'connection'
    else:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database='my_db', user='user',
                                password='my_pwd',
                                host=tunnel.local_bind_host,
                                port=tunnel.local_bind_port)

        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("""
            select * from pricing.public.seller_tiers ;
            """)
        result = cur.fetchall()

        # Getting Field Header names

        column_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
        fp = gzip.open(path, 'wb')
        myFile = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
        myFile.writerow(column_names)
        myFile.writerows(result)
        fp.close()
        conn.close
        tunnel.stop
```

Any ideas or suggestions? I am new to python/airflow so anything would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error would be with respect to the way you are using gzip writer file content.

You are trying to open the gzip file in byte mode and writing string to it, in here `fp = gzip.open(path, 'wb')`.

As per python documentation in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) it's stated:

> 'rt', 'at', 'wt', or 'xt' for text mode.

Change your code to use `wt` which is write text or use encode feature to encode to bytes:

```
 import gzip
 import csv

 with gzip.open("sample.gz", "wt") as gz_fp:
     fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
     writer = csv.writer(gz_fp, delimiter=",")

     writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
     writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
     writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

If you want to write bytes only then:

```
with gzip.open('file.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write('Hello world!'.encode())
```